# If Dignam is not of Irish descent, then who is Frank referring to with the Irish derogatory term?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

While on the phone with Frank in *The Departed* (2006), Sullivan shares his disapproval about Costello's
crew pushing Queenan to his death. Frank defends the action stating that one
person had to die and disregards Dignam and his departure. Sullivan is upset
that he no longer has access to the information that Queenan had:

> Sullivan: He put in his papers, Frank.He left. I don't know where he
> is.
>
> Frank: Don't get your balls in an uproar, Collie. **That Irish
> pissant**... he's so hot for me, we give him a whiff of my ass, he'll
> crawl right in it.  Let's give him a whiff.

If Dignam is not of Irish descent, then who is Frank referring to with the Irish derogatory term?

Comment: "*If Dignam is not of Irish descent*": what makes you say that?

Comment: To be honest, right now I feel this question lacks any and all point. While it has a good answer, that only says "well, then maybe he *is* ...well...Irish, ya know", which is the core problem with the question. **Why do you think he's not of Irish descent?** That is the entire premise of your question and you need to clarify where that's from before there's any sense to it.

Comment: Dignam is Gaelic in origin. So "Sean Dignam" would be extra-uber Irish.  https://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Dignam

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - You appear to have used your moderator powers as a "super-downvote" here. The fact that OP was mistaken about the Irish ancestry of a character [**who speaks with a strong American accent**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vInFuLgwR1U) doesn't seem like a good reason to close their question.

Comment: @Valorum I don't see how this would be a super downvote (in fact I didn't even downvote normally). You don't need to speculate about the reason for closing the question, I stated it right there in the comment. The question as it is lacks *any* kind of explanation for its premise. The question is severly missing this context. Of course I can ask "why is the sky green?", but that isn't much of a sensible question and an answer saying "actually it's blue, duh!" doesn't improve that in any way. *If* his accent was the reason to think he's not of Irish descent, that needs to go into the question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Often, fixing a faulty premise makes for a useful Q&A pair, especially if said premise is a common or understandable misconception.

Comment: @Randal'Thor But what is it? What common misconception? There is no misconception because *no reason at all* is mentioned. I just have no idea why he thinks Dignam isn't of Irish descent (or any at all). The movie just doesn't make a mention to the opposite, so by the fact people call him Irish, he is. I don't get it. If any of you understand why the question is, please fix it. I can't fix it if I don't understand what the question is actually about. If it was common or understandable, it'd already been fixed.

Comment: In fact I implore you, now that this has been reopened (and people would freak the hell out if a moderator just reclosed it), please, if any of you get what on earth this question is about (and you ought to, since you reopened it), help everyone else understand the point of this question and *actually fix it*.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I don't understand what's unclear, so I don't know what edit to make. The Q&A seem clear to me: "who does this Irish epithet refer to, if Dignam isn't Irish?" - "actually he probably is Irish". Why the OP thinks he isn't Irish, we don't know, but why does that matter?

Comment: @Randal'Thor It matters because it is the *entire premise* of the question. "Why is this direct quote from the film contradicting my arbitrary ungrounded assumption about this character?". Can you genuinely not see the problem with making up a wild claim in your head and then wondering why the film contradicts it? *What is the point?* The fact the the assumption was bollocks in the first place, makes the *entire question moot*. Now if we knew *where* that assumption actually came from, this can be adressed. But without that context, the asker now knows as much as without the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If Dignam is not of Irish descent

It's not clear if he's not. It's never mentioned AFAIR.

**TL;DR**: as his name and accent sound so Irish, no wonder one think he's from Irish ancestry and treats him as one. Who Frank talks about could also be *any* cop involved, including Dignam, or Queenan.

As Boston's history is filled with Irish people, culture and accents since the [19th century](https://globalboston.bc.edu/index.php/home/ethnic-groups/irish/#:%7E:text=Irish%20immigration%20to%20Boston%20began%20in%20the%20colonial%20period%20with%20the%20arrival%20of%20predominantly%20Protestant%20migrants%20from%20Ulster), many names are from [Irish ancestry](https://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=dignam#:%7E:text=Irish%3A%20from%20Gaelic%20%C3%93%20Duibhgeann%C3%A1in,homestead%27%20but%20this%20is%20implausible.). The name [Dignam](https://www.google.com/search?q=dignam+last+name+in+ireland) itself seems to find its origin in Ireland.

In the movie, [Mark Wahlberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Wahlberg#Early_life_and_family) plays Sgt Dignam, and the actor was born and raised in Boston. His accent is said to be the best of all actors in the movie.

> Mark Wahlberg is from Dorchester, a town whose name, when pronounced with a Boston accent, is the most New England thing ever. Dawww-chest-ahhh. Unlike Damon, Wahlberg seems to really remember what it sounds like to be from the region, and it pays off. Everything he utters in The Departed is so purely Boston, with the perfect amount of dropped Rs, a complete butchering of the hard-O sound, and a nice hint of impotent outrage that lends the accent its attitude. It's marvelous. Mark Wahlberg should only play people from Boston. [The departed - accents ranking](https://www.complex.com/pop-culture/a/andrew-gruttadaro/the-departed-boston-accents-ranking)

Comment: His accent is Irish? He sounds American to me

Comment: As a foreigner who lived for years in the US, I can hear a difference when people speak, but I can't say where it comes from specifically (but Texas and Georgia because I lived and work with people from those states).  Native say his accent from MA seems clearly from Irish background though.